# Access to a tab directly from an url

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have this tabsbar that I need to access from the url :

```
<div class="tabsbar">
<ul id="myTabs" class="nav">    
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#block_edit_content"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i>Content</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#widget_configure"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i>Configuration</a>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

Here's the jQuery tab function :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#myTabs').tab();
 });
```

Why, when i type this at url bar it doesn't show the requested tab but only the first one? :
`http://www.example.com/block/edit/a/bid/3#widget_configure`
Any help whit this? Thanks.

Comment: I've assumed you're using jQuery UI Tabs and re-tagged accordingly. Please correct it yourself if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think that won't work because there is no click event got fired even if you have your tab's href added in the url itself. There is a workaround you can do like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#myTabs').tab();
    var tabid = window.location.hash;
    if(tabid.length !== 0){
       $('#myTabs').find('a[href*="' + tabid + '"]').trigger('click');
    }

});
```